# Getting error when Zend Cache module is used in php project

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using zend framework cache module in my php project

My folder structure like this

```
myProject
    *library
        *Zend
            *cache
            *cache.php 
    *tmp
    *index.php
```

then it will work.But if i put index.php inside a new folder it is giving error

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Exception.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\library\Zend\Cache\Exception.php on line 25

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Exception.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\library') in C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\library\Zend\Cache\Exception.php on line 25
```

Comment: Have you change the path of the library in your index.php?

Comment: In a first time, take all the Zend library to find out what its exception. After delete the files so do not need Zend Cache (obviously he needs Exception.php file :))

Comment: Do you have file `C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\library\Zend\Cache\Exception.php`?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider two things here:

1. You should have C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\library\Zend\Cache\Exception.php (what is Volvox already asked)
2. Check to see how zend cache is included in index.php. Most likely it has relative path which is not so cool.

I would recommend to have some kind of ROOT_DIR or APPLICATION_PATH constant and use this constant with relative path like:

```
define('APPLICATION_PATH', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\');
include_once(APPLICATION_PATH . 'library\Zend\Cache.php');
```

Having index.php like this will make it possible to move it around the project without any problems